# How to handle the state when multiple components use the same actions in Vuex for fetching data?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have been using Vuex to control my whole app state for a while. But now I am facing a problem I have never meet before.

The Workflow is like this:

1. The root component will fetch data from my database, which is an array with multiple objects in it.
2. I created child-component and use v-for to show this array to user (that means, each child-component represents an object in the array later)
3. The Problem comes, when I try to fetch async data for each child-component, for the data-fetching, I also need parameter which come from the array I mentioned.
4. I use the Vuex actions in the created hook of my child components. The actions `fetch_sim_Type` will take the payload (which is parameter from parent-component, also from the initial array). And change the state `simType` in the `state: {}` of Vuex.
5. By using the computed properties I can get the fetched `simType` in my child-component and show it to the user. Everything works so far.

### CODES:

THE initial Array (simSumArray in Parent-component) looks like this:

```
[
    { typeid: 1, name: XXX },
    { typeid: 2, name: ZZZ },
    { typeid: 3, name: GGG },
    { typeid: 4, name: JJJ },
]
```

PARENT-COMPONENT:

```
<template
    v-for="(singleSim, idx) in simSumArray"
>
    <sim-single :singleSim="singleSim"></sim-single>
</template>
```

CHILD-COMPONENTS:

```
props: ['singleSim'],
created () {
    store.dispatch('fetch_sim_Type', this.singleSim.typeid);
},
computed: {
    simType () {
        console.log("store.getters.get_simType: ", store.getters.get_simType)
        return store.getters.get_simType;
    }
},
```

IN VUEX:

```
state: {
    simType: 'unknown'
},
actions: {
    fetch_sim_Type (context, typeid) {
        //.. fetch the data based on typeid from DB
        context.state.simType = fetchedData;
    }
}
```

But it only works when in the array only when object exist. When there are more than one child-component being created. The state simType in the Vuex store.js will be replaced many times and in every child-component the simType() is always the same.

The Problem is kind of hard to describe. **The central problem is, the state in Vuex is meant to be shared everywhere in the whole app, so if I have multiple child-components, they all fetch data for themself, than the shared state will be replaced all the time and I can't get individual state for every child-components.**

I don't know if I describe the problem clair but I really tried hard to.
Maybe There is a better way to do this data fetching job without Vuex or maybe I just used the Vuex by the wrong way.

I am sure this should not be a hard question. But I can't find any relative answer online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your code, the behaviour you describe is normal. I see two solution to your problem (solution 2 is probably closer to what you are looking for) :

**Solution 1 - store simType in your component**

*if you need to access the simType from somewhere else than inside your component and have it stored in your state, skip to solution 2*

When your component is created, store the simtype in the component's data. This would look like this:

In your component:

```
data () {
    return {
       simType: undefined //declare simType as one of your component's data property
    }
},
created () {
    store.dispatch('fetch_sim_Type', this.singleSim.typeid).then(simType => {
        this.simType = simType //store the fetched simType
    })
}
```

In your vuex Actions:

```
actions: {
    fetch_sim_Type (context, typeid) {
        //.. fetch the data based on typeid from DB
        return fetchedData //pretty much the same except return the result
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 - store simTypes in your state indexed by their IDs**

Store your fetched simType by id, like this:

```
state: {
    simTypes: {} //simTypes is now plural, and is an empty object at first. It will later contain several simTypes, indexed by their respective Ids
},
actions: {
    fetch_sim_Type (context, typeid) {
        //.. fetch the data based on typeid from DB
        context.state.simType[typeid] = fetchedData; // a fetched simtyped will be store in simTypes and can be accessed with the typeid as a key
    }
}
```

to retrieve a simType, you can write a vuex getter like this:

```
getters: {
  getSimTypeById: (state) => (typeId) => {
    return state.simTypes[typeId]
  }
}
```

So in your example, the computed method would be :

```
computed: {
    simType () {
        console.log("store.getters.getSimTypeById(this.singleSim.typeid): ", store.getters.getSimTypeById(this.singleSim.typeid)
        return store.getters.getSimTypeById(this.singleSim.typeid);
    }
},
```

This solution, as a bonus, allows you to fetch a simType only once if several of your items have the same simType.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a very good and well explained answer. I took the solution 2 for me. It was all good but the getter for getting the fetched data is actually wrong. With  `return state.simTypes[typeId]` I got "undefined". And I also searched it on google. I finally change the actions a little bit with `context.state.simTypes.push({ "typeid": typeid, "simType": simType });` and used `return state.simTypes.find(simType => simType.typeid == typeid)` and got it all work! Finaly! thank you!

Comment: sorry for the getter, i actually have no mean of testing what I write right now, and thank you for correcting it :) Although it might have been because your `simTypes`  was still an array and not an object ? Anyway, glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

I have had success by keeping shared data in the Vuex store, and watching it from my components.

Although not a best practice, I sometimes don't even bother to use actions or commits to change the state, and just modify the state directly.  In this scenario, Vuex just acts like a shared `data` object for all my components.

Vue Store

```
state: {
   myvalue: []
}
```

Components

```
watch: {
  '$store.state.myvalue'(value) {
  }
}
```